# Flutter 2: How make an infinite multiline textfield use the parameter `onEditingComplete`

Tags: flutter, textfield

I am trying to figure it out a blocking point related to the multiline of a Textfield using `onEditingComplete`.

[image]

[image]

```
TextField(
    onSubmitted: (value) {
      print(value);
    },
    maxLines: null,
),
```

How, with a multiline textfield, can we use the parameter `onEditingComplete` ?

Comment: What's your target?

Comment: I would like to have a way to complete the edition of an infinite multiline textfield (the best way would be only by using the keyboard)